# Как реализовать загрузку файла React?

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите, где можно найти готовую реализацию загрузки файла на react

У меня есть окно, в котором ссылка. При нажатии на нее, должно появляться окно, где можно выбрать файл и загрузить его.
Так называемый Uploader.
при нажатии на "закрыть" файл удаляется/
Плагинами пользоваться нельзя

Comment: Попробуйте https://github.com/navjobs/upload Он предоставляет данный функционал.

Comment: а без плагинов? по сути нужно только сделать,чтобы при нажатии на ссылку появлялось окно и загружался файл. без drag-in-drop

Comment: вот что-то подобное https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695275/react-js-handling-file-upload

Comment: а нужно ли взаимодействие с сервером осуществлять? 
вот у меня есть форма. и поле "прикрепить резюме". При нажатии на ссылку "прикрепить резюме" открывается просто окно, выбираем файл.
и он загружается как в демо здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39695275/react-js-handling-file-upload


далее при сабмите формы мне нужно будет его как-то отправлять. сделать можно такой же метод как в демо ?

Comment: да, на сервере надо сохранить файл, который пришел через POST и вернуть ответ, что все успешно прошло.

Comment: А как реализовать удаление файла при нажатии на какую-нибудь кнопку после загрузки?